# How does overlapped/asynchronous I/O work

Tags: c++, asynchronous, synchronization, readfile

Supposed I have something like this

```
readFile(.....&ol) //with overlapped

while(1){

////////.....
waitforsingleobject(//ol.hevent);

////

readfile(.....&ol)

}
```

I noticed that both readfiles read from the beginning of the file...why?  In a  normal readfile without overlapped/asynchronization the second readfile would start off where the first ended..

Comment: To increase your chances of getting help: 1. Post a complete compilable code fragment that demonstrates the behavior. 2. Tag the question appropriately.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx I suggest MSDN is the reference for questions regarding Microsoft API functions and parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using overlapped I/O on a file, you pass a pointer to an `OVERLAPPED` object, in this case `ol`.

The `OVERLAPPED` struct has two variables, `Offset` and `OffsetHigh`. These two variables are combined into a 64-bit integer, with `Offset` being the lower-order DWORD and `OffsetHigh` being the high-order DWORD, and used as the offset to perform the I/O operation at.

So, for example, if you wanted to start a `ReadFile` at the 8th byte of the file, you would set the `Offset` variable to 8 and the `OffsetHigh` variable to 0 before passing the `OVERLAPPED` to `ReadFile`.

Comment: As an extra tip: this is only required for reading *files*.  When using asynchronous I/O with sockets, setting this member is not necessary.